# 'make' command is not working within terminal VScode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, command-line, terminal

I feel like this is a very trivial question, I cannot figure out for the life of me what is going on with my VScode.

```
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ make
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

Suggestion [3,General]: The command make was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\make". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

I am just trying to compile two files together to make them work. They compile and execute seperately, but when I use the 'make' command, in the terminal within VS, it delivers this error.
I believe that my makefile is setup correctly, literally following my professors video on how to do it and it's working properly.

Any pointers??

Comment: Pointers? How about the pointer given to you by the error itself? Specifically, `If you trust this command, instead type: ".\make".`

Answer (score -1):

As the message says: Make command is not found!

1. Make sure your make command does exist by simply typing make and hitting enter.
2. if it does not exist install both: build-essentials and make using pip/conda/npm/npx

These are the main rules to make the target work!